# javascript evaluate the expression containing the array literal each time

Tags: javascript, arrays, expression, evaluate

> If an array is created using a literal in a top-level script, JavaScript interprets the array each time it evaluates the expression containing the array literal.

Source: [MDN, "Values, variables, and literals"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Array_literals)

I can't understand it well.
Someone can give me a example detailly.

Comment: @AmitJoki The quote is from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Array_literals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Without knowing more context, it's hard to say what the author meant. (I checked, that text isn't from the spec.)</s> Okay, now we know the source of the quote, I've checked, and the below applies.

Say you have this script:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
```

Every time that script is evaluated, that array initialiser ("literal") is evaluated. The array isn't created once and cached. In browser applications, it's rare to re-evaluate the top-level script without reloading the entire environment, but it's *possible* to do it, and if you do a new array is created each time.

I don't know why the quote would say "...in a top-level script..." as this is true anywhere. For instance:

```
function foo() {
    var a = [1, 2, 3];

    // ...
}
```

Every call to `foo` results in a *new* array. The expression, like all expressions, is evaluated every time it is encountered. *(There was a bug in the ES3 spec in this regard around regular expression literals, but it was fixed in ES5.)*

Comment: thank you. I got confused by myself.The array literal of course will be evaluated each time.

Comment: @kuma: Not by yourself, that sentence is really weird. :-)